# add new trackable data and movie in vuforia viedoplayback sample

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I successfully run the vuforia AR viedoplayback sample in my device.
When i run the application it can track the image provided with the sample and can play movie according to image.

But i want to add new trackable data and new movie in this sample.Please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve this problem by asking question to vuforia sdk official forum.Here is the procedure

https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/add-my-new-trackable-data-and-movie-viedoplayback-sample